# How to connect flutter app to AWS EC2 Instance via HTTP request

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, amazon-ec2

I setup an EC2 instance and I Have been able to setup Apache, Mysql and PHPmyadmin on the server, I have also been able to create a php file that returns a JSON response from the items i have in a Mysql Database, when I access the public ip address of the EC2 instance, I can view the JSON response I returned from the PHP script (myipadress/get.php). The issue I have right now is that when I try to make an HTTP request using the flutter Http package, i get the error message below

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = myipadress, port = 41038
```

I believe this error might have to do with my AWS EC2 instance ports, but i can't seem to find a way to fix this.

Comment: What is your security group configuration on the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem was not with the AWS EC2 Instance, the issue was as a result of the way I made the http request.

Below is the URI i was parsing into the request.

```
final uri = Uri.https('myIpAdress', '/get.php');
```

I solved the problem by switching it to the code below, was formerly using https then switched to http.

```
final uri = Uri.http('myIpAdress', '/get.php');
```